# Using “put” command in sftp gives No such file or directory 3: Permission denied

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm trying to retrieve some files from sftp server using JSch but I'm getting the following error.

```
ls: cannot access /export/user-docs/adminuser/record/WAQ12.txt: No such file or directory
    3: Permission denied, file: /opt/ftp/pub/new_waq_std/WAQ12.txt
    @at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    @at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:768)
    @at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:709)
    @at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:703)
```

Here is the code:

```
class WSFTPFile {
       static WSFTPFile ftpFile =null;
        private static ChannelSftp sftp;
        private static Session jschSession;
       WSDBTool dbTool= null;
           boolean stickyCRLF=false;
           boolean seenCR=false;

       public static WSFTPFile getInstance(){
           if (ftpFile == null)
              ftpFile =  new WSFTPFile();
           return ftpFile;
       }

       public void performFTP(Vector<String> v) throws Exception {

             /*SFTP Coding start */
            int authResult = -1;
             JSch jsch = new JSch();

            try{

            jsch.addIdentity(dbTool.getSourceDirectory()
                    + "id_rsa_1234.wsadmin");

            jschSession = (Session) jsch.getSession(dbTool.getFTPUserName(),
                    dbTool.getFTPIP(), 22);
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            jschSession.setConfig(config);
            jschSession.connect();
            System.out.println("Host connected.");

            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in connecting to SFTP server.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // SftpClient sftp;
            System.out.println("authResult:" + authResult);

                if (jschSession.isConnected()) {    
                try{
                    sftp = (ChannelSftp)jschSession.openChannel("sftp") ;
                    sftp.connect();
                    //sftp = sshClient.openSftpClient();
                    sftp.lcd(dbTool.getSourceDirectory());
                    sftp.cd(dbTool.getFileDirectory());

                    sftp.put(dbTool.getSourceDirectory()+dbTool.getFileName(),dbTool.getFileName(),ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
                    if(sftp != null) {
                        sftp.disconnect();  
                        sftp.quit();
                        sftp = null;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Successfully connected to ws  SFTP area..");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Exception in SFTP put.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error connecting SFTP server.");
            }
                if(jschSession != null){
                     jschSession.disconnect();
                     jschSession = null;
                }
             /*SFTP Coding END*/
            System.out.println("File sent to ws  via SFTP");
        }
        }
```

Below is what i get when i run ls -alF in the ftp directory:-

-rw-r--r-- 1 ssrftp ssssftp 3135 May 16 17:00 WAQ12.txt

But my existing WAQ12.txt is like 2 months old in the ftp location and it gives me the above error while trying to do ftp. Does the date of the file matters? Any idea?
  NOTE:- For testing, i deleted the existing WAQ12.txt in the location /export/user-docs/adminuser/record/WAQ12.txt and ran my program , it worked fine and populated the file  WAQ12.txt in the ftp location and again when i ran the program it did overwrite the previous WAQ12.txt and the timestamp got updated.

But i don't want to that, i want the previous WAQ12.txt(which is 2 months old) file to be overwritten by the new file when i run my program, but i am keep getting the above error. Any idea?

Comment: Does used which is returned by `dbTool.getFTPUserName()` has write permissions for existing WAQ12.txt file in remote location?

Comment: Yes Ivan , dbTool.getFTPUserName() has write permission , please go through my query again , i have updated some info

Comment: How about write permission to the directory the file is in? Run the command  ls -alF in the directory and paste the output here

Comment: 1028358 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 ssftp sssftp 3135 May 16 17:00 WAQ12.txt for the ftp location when i did ls -list WAQ12.txt

Comment: Prerna: that should be `ls -alF` (or just `ls -al` or `ls -la` as the `-F` isn't really needed here). `ls -list` means `ls -l -i -s -t` which is wrong because `-i -s -t` are useless here, `-l` is useful but not sufficient because you need `-a`. And add important info like this to your Question by editting; comments have very restricted formatting and are transient (i.e. may be deleted) because Stack is designed specifically NOT to be a chat room.

Comment: So are you saying that you can upload the file, if it does not exist yet on the server. But if it exists already, you cannot replace it? Even if the previous copy was created by your own program? - Did you try doing the same using any standalone SFTP client? Does it work then?

Comment: ls -la shows -rw-r--r-- 1 ssrftp ssssftp 3135 May 16 17:00 WAQ12.txt, can you please exlplain me what exactly it shows

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the ftp user has write permissions to the directory, too. When replacing an existing file, the put command first deletes and then uploads the file in question. The delete part fails if you don't have write permissions on the directory.

Change permissions with the `chmod` command. For testing, you could try `sudo chmod a+w .` to give **all** users write permissions to the directory. If it works, adjust the permissions set to the smallest scope possible, e.g. only the group text sftp user belongs to.

Comment: *"When replacing an existing file, the put command first deletes and then uploads the file in question."* - No it does not! - At least not on a common setups (a common Linux distribution running OpenSSH SFTP server). `put` overwrites a file. It does not delete and re-create a new one. So you do not need delete permissions (write permissions to a folder) to overwrite a file.